# Could not establish DB connection from Servlet

Tags: servlets, jdbc

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /*Fields are correct*/
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        Connection sqlCon = DB.getConnection();
        if (null == sqlCon) {
            System.out.println("Could not establish connection.");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection successful.");
        }
    }
}

public class DB {
    /*Fields are correct*/
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVERS);
            sqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);

        } catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException cnfe) {
            System.out.println("Drivers Problem.: " + cnfe);
        }
        return sqlCon;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection sqlCon = DB.getConnection();
        if (null == sqlCon) {
            System.out.println("Could not establish connection.");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection successful.");
        }
    }
}
```

After I execute servlet, I always get Exception

```
Drivers Problem.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Could not establish connection.
```

Surprisingly when I execute `DB.main()` I could establish connection without any issue. What might be the problem?

I am using Eclipse/Apache Tomcat 8. Codes are clipped, but all correct. This question is about servlet not Jav to MySQL only.. My connections are successful but not with servlet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect Java to a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/connect-java-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Solution does not work in my case

Comment: Execute `main` is done differently from executing a servlet. In both cases you must make sure the driver is on the classpath.

Comment: Anyways I marked correct answer, and its different than _Duplicate_ one.

Comment: step 2 of http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/466862 implies this; although the answer handles the general case and not the specifics of a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the JAR file with mysql JDBC driver either into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp, or into the Tomcat's `lib` folder.